# Eclipse ругается на RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. В файл разметки добавляю RecyclerView:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />
```

В Activity инциализирую его:

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
```

Но на эту строку ругается Eclipse
`Multiple markers at this line
    - RecyclerView cannot be resolved 
     to a type
    - RecyclerView cannot be resolved 
     to a type` 
Буду благодарен за помощь в решении проблемы!

Comment: А библиотеку нужную вы подключили?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего просто не подключена библиотека к проекту.

Для её подключения можно, например, скопировать jar файл с соответствующим названием из папки `extras/android/support/v7/` в папку **libs**.

Comment: а где взять эту библиотеку?

Comment: Проверьте скачана ли она через SDKManager и ищите в папке куда SDKManager всё скачивает.